# ORA-00984: column not allowed here ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle

I'm trying to store my image into database which have blob datatype and I have created blob named byte which stores all content of that image. I have created a method called `ReadFile(FullPath)` to get the image content, but while storing this value I'm getting an following error :

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
string file_id_is = db.getData(select_fileid_query).ToString();
int I_File_Id = Convert.ToInt32(file_id_is);
string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
string FileContentType = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.ContentType);
string FullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(PostedFile.FileName);
byte[] blob = ReadFile(FullPath);

string Query = "insert into JOINTING_FILES_DETAILS (ID,DRAFTSMAN_FILES_ID,FILE_NAME,CONTENT_TYPE,DATA)
values (JOINTING_UPLOADED_SEQ.NEXVAL,:file_id,:FileNameis,:FileType,:BlobParameter)";
using (OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(Query, connection.get()))
{
    try
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("file_id", I_File_Id);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("FileNameis", FileName);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("FileType", FileContentType);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("BlobParameter", blob);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.Message)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `JOINTING_UPLOADED_SEQ.NEXVAL`? This sounds like a column name rather than a value.

Comment: `JOINTING_UPLOADED_SEQ` is my sequence that i have created in oracle for incremental id for this table

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you made a typo for accessing the next value of the sequence. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm) to use this

So try changing

```
JOINTING_UPLOADED_SEQ.NEXVAL
```

to

```
JOINTING_UPLOADED_SEQ.NEXTVAL
```

Comment: Yes i forgot to put `T` ,  silly spelling/syntax mistake, now it's fine